# Seaborn pairplot data not shown

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, seaborn

I decided to try out Seaborn's pairplot, but the following line of code (https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) is giving me a plot without the data appearing:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
>>> sns.set(font='monospace')
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.pairplot(iris)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: empty pairplot of iris dataset]

What is going on with my plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have encountered a bug in matplotlib 1.3. The solution is to upgrade your matplotlib.

Comment: Along with updating matplotlib, I needed libffi-dev and cairocffi. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot upgrade matplotlib for some reason a workaround is this, which generates nearly the desired plots in matplotlib 1.3.1:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
def scatter_fake_diag(x, y, *a, **kw):
    if x.equals(y):
        kw["color"] = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    plt.scatter(x, y, *a, **kw)

g.map(scatter_fake_diag)
g.map_diag(plt.hist)
```

[image: workaroung_figure]

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

1. Uninstall seaborn, then reinstall seaborn
2. Uninstall matplotlib and seaborn, then reinstall matplotlib, then reinstall seaborn.